# textbox.lines() не возвращает массив строк

Tags: vb.net

Почему **textbox.lines()** не возвращает массив строк, несмотря что на экране текст в textbox написан в нескольких строках.

```
dim txtDlg as new textbox
txtDlg.Multiline = true
txtDlg.WordWrap = true
.......................
AddHandler txtDlg,TextChanged, addressOf HandleTextChange
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Private sub HandleTextChange(sender as object, e As EventArgs)
dim txtBox As Textbox = DirectCast(sender, textBox)
dim txtArray() as String

txtArray=txtDlg.lines()

End sub
```

То же происходит и с RichTextBox, т.е. получаю одну длинную строку, без
символов конца и переноса строки!
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: отформатируйте пожалуйста текст

Comment: Разве lines является методом? Попробуйте не вызывать у него круглые скобки, т.к., судя по документации, это свойство: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

Comment: Конечно без скобок. Это просто описка при переписывания с текста программы. Спасибо.